# « Dans mon collège » ou « à mon collège »?

Tags: grammaire

Which is the correct choice of grammar in this sentence?

**Il était une langue étrangère à apprendre dans mon collège.**

or

**Il était une langue étrangère à apprendre à mon collège.**

In my opinion, « à » works better because I am not saying the physical school building offers this foreign language course, but was taught by my teachers at my school.

Comment: Likely *dans mon collège* but what is the expected meaning of the whole sentence?

Comment: @jlliagre The expected meaning is that French was a foreign language taught at my middle school.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The right form is ***dans*** mon collège.

Note that the remaining of the sentence needs some improvement:

> *C'était une langue étrangère enseignée **dans** mon collège.*

We don't use ***à*** because that would mean the language was taught "to the school".

Compare to *j'ai appris le français **à** mon frère*: I taught French to my brother.

Without the possessive, you can use *à* like in these sentences:

> *C'est une langue étrangère que j'ai apprise **à** l'école:* That's a foreign language I learnt at school.

or

> *... que j'ai apprise **au** collège.*